# Can A Remote Contractor Be Requested to be Available Virtually at All Times?

Tags: software-industry, united-states, contractors

I am working as a contractor in the US here remotely full time
and I communicate with my team through Skype.
Usually we receive the requirements for a project once a week and 
we dash off to do our own work.

Can the person whom I report to request that I be availble on all the time?  If I were a full time employee, then that would be a valid request. But I am not sure for contractors.

One time my manager was complaining to me that I wasn't responsive in Skype.

Comment: Saying which State you're in can certainly help answers around here - I don't *think* it should change the answers a whole lot since most of the contractor definition stuff is on federal IRS rules and such, but states handle labor laws in general.

Comment: Your manager can *request* almost anything. It's up to you to decide if their requests are reasonable and covered under your contract, and respond accordingly.

Comment: 1. They can request anything they want. That doesn't mean that you have to abide or oblige them. 2. If they "require" you to do certain things or if they attempt to exert a certain amount of control over you or to dictate certain aspects of your working relationship with them then they very well could be putting themselves in a tough spot with the IRS if they're mis-classifying you.

Comment: How exactly does "not being responsive" look like? Are you gone for hours until you answer, or is it just a question of 5-10min while you are really concentrated on a task. The first one is a problem, the second one is totally ok and even common when working in an office (at least in the software industry, can't really say about other areas).

Comment: Does being available "all the time" mean during regular office hours or 24x7?

Answer (score 7):

> I am working as a contractor in the US here remotely full time

So how many hours do you bill as full time (per day)?

Agree a timeslot (of your billable hours) that you are responsive, and maybe agree you may respond outwith but not as quickly.

If you are being paid to work a certain time is reasonable for them to expect you will be contactable during that time.